# select recursive for search

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an option to search all IDINTERNAL  until the last, keep in mind that everyone is on the same table and each record refers to the immediate parent

my table is:

```
idInternal              idFather
------------        |   ---------
79          |   0
80          |   79
83          |   79
89          |   79
119         |   79
120         |   79
81          |   80
82          |   80
84          |   83
85          |   83
117         |   83
98          |   89
99          |   89
121         |   89
```

my old query:

```
SELECT * FROM MENU WHERE IdFather IN (
         SELECT IDINTERNAL FROM MENU WHERE IdFather IN (
         SELECT IDINTERNAL FROM MENU WHERE IdFather IN (
         SELECT IDINTERNAL FROM MENU WHERE IdFather IN (SELECT IDINTERNAL FROM MENU  WHERE IdFather = 79)
         )
         )
         )
```

note that each record in the table is an immediate child of another record

thanks for advance

--- this is the query to find all the children of id 79:

DECLARE @id INT
    SET @id = 79;

```
WITH hierarchy AS (
  SELECT t.idInternal, t.idpadre
    FROM menu t
   WHERE t.idInternal = @id
 UNION ALL
 SELECT x.idInternal, x.idpadre
   FROM menu x
   JOIN hierarchy h ON h.idInternal = x.idpadre)
 SELECT h.idInternal
  FROM hierarchy h
```

Comment: if it's sql server 2008, you may find this useful http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx - usually, every major DBMS has its own trick to do recursive queries

Comment: You'll have referential integrity issues if your idInternal 79 father is itself.  If 79 is the progenitor element, then its idFather should be null.

Comment: True just edit the question and tried to link @MichalBrašna  and works well, I would like to put the answer but I have to wait 8 hours ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for menu 121 and you want to get all menus from 121 to the top, you'd do something like this:

```
declare @id int
set @id = 121

;with cte as
(
    select * from Menu where idInternal = @id
    union all

    select m.* 
    from Menu m
    inner join cte on m.idInternal = cte.idFather
)
select * from cte
```

To do a top down traversal you would do something like this:

```
declare @id int
set @id = 79

;with cte AS (
    select idFather from Menu where idInternal = @id
), tree as (
    select m1.idFather, m1.idInternal
    from Menu m1
    inner join cte on m1.idFather = cte.idFather
    union all
    select m2.idFather, m2.idInternal
    from Menu m2
    inner join tree t ON m2.idFather = t.idInternal
)
select * from tree
```

Comment: I really needed to see all the children of id 79

Comment: children, grandchildren, great grandchildren, etc.

Comment: Its ok, gave me an idea to find my answer, edit I just put my answer in the end, thank you very much.